# Java audio... getting from byte[] of raw waveform to playable Clip

Tags: java, audio

I'm trying to figure out how to play a raw 8-bit (signed) waveform using Java, and struggling because it seems like every API example I find assumes media playback from a file. Here's what I have so far (shortened for clarity):

```
// Assume waveform array has 480 bytes, and consists of 24 periods of a 1000hz sine wave.
byte[] waveform = WaveformGenerator.generateWaveform();

Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
ByteArrayInputStream fakeInputStream= new ByteArrayInputStream(waveform);
AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(fakeInputStream);
clip.open(inputStream);
clip.start();
```

When it runs, AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(fakeInputStream) throws
`javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: Stream of unsupported format`
before it even *makes* it to clip.open(inputStream);

ok, fair enough... I guess I need to tell it that it's a mono 8-bit PCM waveform. So, I created an AudioFormat to let it know that it's 48khz 8-bit PCM...

```
AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 48000, 8, 1, 1, 48000, false);
```

... then realized (too late) that the variant of AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream() that allows you to specify the format requires that you *already have* an AudioInputStream. As far as I can tell, there's no variant of getAudioInputStream that allows you to SIMULTANEOUSLY specify its type *and* content.

Obviously, I'm going down the wrong track here. So... what *is* the correct way to get from a byte array containing a raw 8-bit signed PCM waveform to an audio object that can be play()'ed?

Comment: Does calling the constructor directly work? Something like `AudioInputStream inputStream = new AudioInputStream(fakeInputStream, audioFormat, waveform.length);`

Comment: Yep, that did it! Go ahead & post it as an answer & I'll accept it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the constructor directly like this:

```java
AudioInputStream inputStream = new AudioInputStream(fakeInputStream, audioFormat, waveform.length);
```